# XCode на Macbook Air?

Tags: xcode

Если взять Macbook Air 11.6" i5 1.6GHz 2Gb - как на нем будет XCode? Потянет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Очень даже потянет. Разве что памяти по-хорошему надо больше, иначе при одновременной работе с Xcode остальным приложениям памяти будет не хватать.
Я работаю на Mac Mini 2010 с куда более слабым процессором и не жалуюсь особо.

Ах, да. 11 дюймов - далеко не комфортный размер экрана для работы с Xcode (да и с любым другим приложением, в общем то) - придется скрывать почти все панели и разворачивать на весь экран.

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень признателен.

Answer (score 0):

Да, а почему бы макбук через переходник не подключить к простому монитору, подключить клавиатуру, мышь и вуаля, вот оно счастье)

Comment: Ну мне всегда казалось, что те, кто берет Air - рассчитывают именно на мобильность и возможность поработать в дороге. А так - да, можно и внешний монитор юзать.

Comment: ну может быть Эир был подарен, а как говорится даренному коню в зубы не смотрят)))